# Facing a issue with unique() function in R and class of objects

Tags: r, csv, unique

I'm merging multiple files together and then trying to get the unique data out of a particular column. This idea works perfectly fine, when I'm running the code for a single pattern.

```
united_tweets <- load_data("united")
nrow(united_tweets)
united_unique <- unique(united_tweets[,2])
```

But, When i run the same code inside a for loop , the unique function seems to create an error. The output of a unique function, or when i try to get a single column saved , the class of the variable changes from 'list' to 'factor'. Trying to find unique values from it returns NULL values. Can someone point out what is wrong here?

```
  for(i in 1:length(airlines)){
        tmp <- load_data(airlines[i])
        tweet <- as.list(tmp$text)
        print(class(tweet))
        tmp1 <- as.list(unique.default(tweet))
        print(nrow(tmp1))
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the data that you are working on or part of it. I want to run the code and see what is happening.

Comment: I am just taking the twitter data. As I have to take it during different time periods, I have stored them in different files and am accumulating them in a folder. While doing analysis, i want to take them all together and get rid of duplicates. I have the files available here if you want. https://github.com/curiouscoder007/R-airlines

Comment: i think for`list` use `length` not `nrow`. I tried your code and `tmp1` has data in it. Just try `length(tmp1)` instead of `nrow(tmp1)`

Comment: tried the length. it returns 0 instead of NULL. did you get a value when u tried it?

Comment: Doesn't each post have a unique ID? Perhaps you could find their IDs and throw out all but one duplicate? Also, consider storing twitter data to a database...

Comment: RIght. They have a unique ID. i didnt think about that! I'll try with that column as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i used. Only two differences from yours, `read.csv` and `length(tmp1)`.

```
## file names    
airlines = c("Delta03262017123126.csv", "Delta03262017124221.csv")

for(i in 1:length(airlines)){
        tmp <- read.csv(airlines[i])
        tweet <- as.list(tmp$text)
        print(class(tweet))
        tmp1 <- as.list(unique.default(tweet))
        print(length(tmp1))
}

# [1] "list"
# [1] 1
# [1] "list"
# [1] 3495
```